# SSL handshake exception: "Algorithm constraints check failed: MD5withRSA"

Tags: java, ssl

I tried to install Oracle Entitlements Server Client.
When I call

```
config.cmd -smConfigId Sample-SM -prpFileName C:\oracle\product\11.1.2\as_1\oessm\SMConfigTool\smconfig.java.controlled.prp
```

I got this Exception:

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed: MD5withRSA
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
        at oracle.security.oes.enroll.EnrollmentClient.writeToSocket(EnrollmentClient.java:330)
        at oracle.security.oes.enroll.EnrollmentClient.enroll(EnrollmentClient.java:161)
        at oracle.security.oes.enroll.EnrollmentClient.main(EnrollmentClient.java:478)
        at oracle.security.oes.tools.EnrollmentTool.doEnroll(EnrollmentTool.java:103)
        at oracle.security.oes.tools.SMConfigTool.doEnrollment(SMConfigTool.java:1192)
        at oracle.security.oes.tools.SMConfigTool.run(SMConfigTool.java:617)
        at oracle.security.oes.tools.SMConfigTool.main(SMConfigTool.java:546)
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed: MD5withRSA
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:350)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:260)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed: MD5withRSA
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:159)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.doValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:351)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:191)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:279)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:345)
        ... 21 more
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed: MD5withRSA
```

Can you help me to find a reason?

Comment: You might want to decrease the key size for RSA (from the default of 1024, I think, to 256, for example).

Comment: "Starting from 7u40, the use of x.509 certificates with RSA keys less than 1024 bits in length is restricted."  http://java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml . I tried change Java 7 to Java 6 and it worked.

Comment: How to check key length: http://serverfault.com/questions/325467/i-have-a-keypair-how-do-i-determine-the-key-length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[keyser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/645270/keyser) gave direction for answer in comment.

Problem was in key's length. In short: ["Starting from 7u40, the use of x.509 certificates with RSA keys less than 1024 bits in length is restricted."](http://java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml)

So the right way to solve this problem it is using certificates with key's length at least 2048 bits.

Comment: this is working for me also

Answer (score 51):

The problem is caused by Oracle disabling hash algorithms which are no longer considered to be secure. Take a look at

```
JRE_HOME/lib/security/java.security
```

It contains the following properties:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms
```

You can adjust them appropriately. For example, remove **MD5** from the former and **MD5withRSA** from the latter.

Hint for docker images:

there is additional config file `/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config` in some docker images like `keycloak` in my case which overrides values in `java.security`

Comment: That's the ticket. I'm used to having to unscrew VMware components (hello, XP still exists.) I'm not used to having to dumb down java.

Comment: Is there a way to only allow an algorithm from a specific source? I should only be allowing this exception for one or two servers that I trust.

Comment: For a newer version of java the java.security file can be found at JRE_HOME/conf/security/java.security

Comment: Editing `/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config` on Fedora 33 using Java 11 is what I needed for Apache Directory Studio

Comment: @HarlemSquirrel `/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config` was also the solution for the same situation (Java 11, ADS) on RHEL 9.