# PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed: SHA1withRSA

Tags: java, security, ssl, twitter, flume

I am getting `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed: SHA1withRSAsame` error, when I am calling Twitter source from flume. 
When I googled then I came to know that my jdk might be of older version but my jdk version is 1.8.0_45. What could be the problem because I have latest jdk?
Using the command  `keytool -list -keystore /usr/jdk64/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.45-28.b13.el6_6.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts`
I got following output

```
    Keystore type: JKS
    Keystore provider: SUN

    Your keystore contains 161 entries
    extra-tanxc3xbasxc3xadtvxc3xa1nykiadxc3xb3kcertificationservicesnetlockaranyclassgoldfxc5x91tanxc3xbasxc3xadtvxc3xa1ny, Apr 23, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 06:08:3F:59:3F:15:A1:04:A0:69:A4:6B:A9:03:D0:06:B7:97:09:91
    extra-eecertificationcentrerootca, Apr 23, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): C9:A8:B9:E7:55:80:5E:58:E3:53:77:A7:25:EB:AF:C3:7B:27:CC:D7
    extra-dstrootcax3, Apr 23, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): DA:C9:02:4F:54:D8:F6:DF:94:93:5F:B1:73:26:38:CA:6A:D7:7C:13
    extra-dtrustrootclass3ca2ev2009, Apr 23, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 96:C9:1B:0B:95:B4:10:98:42:FA:D0:D8:22:79:FE:60:FA:B9:16:83
    extra-cybertrustglobalroot, Apr 23, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 5F:43:E5:B1:BF:F8:78:8C:AC:1C:C7:CA:4A:9A:C6:22:2B:CC:34:C6
    extra-buypassclass3ca1, Apr 23, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 61:57:3A:11:DF:0E:D8:7E:D5:92:65:22:EA:D0:56:D7:44:B3:23:71
    extra-comodoca, Apr 23, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 66:31:BF:9E:F7:4F:9E:B6:C9:D5:A6:0C:BA:6A:BE:D1:F7:BD:EF:7B
    extra-seewwwentrustnetlegaltermsentrustrootcag2, Apr 23, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 8C:F4:27:FD:79:0C:3A:D1:66:06:8D:E8:1E:57:EF:BB:93:22:72:D4
    utndatacorpsgcca, Apr 23, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 58:11:9F:0E:12:82:87:EA:50:FD:D9:87:45:6F:4F:78:DC:FA:D6:D4
    extra-identrustpublicsectorrootca1, Apr 23, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): BA:29:41:60:77:98:3F:F4:F3:EF:F2:31:05:3B:2E:EA:6D:4D:45:FD
    extra-tsystemstrustcenterttelesecglobalrootclass3, Apr 23, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 55:A6:72:3E:CB:F2:EC:CD:C3:23:74:70:19:9D:2A:BE:11:E3:81:D1
    digicertglobalrootca, Apr 23, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): A8:98:5D:3A:65:E5:E5:C4:B2:D7:D6:6D:40:C6:DD:2F:B1:9C:54:36
    extra-tsystemstrustcenterttelesecglobalrootclass2, Apr 23, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 59:0D:2D:7D:88:4F:40:2E:61:7E:A5:62:32:17:65:CF:17:D8:94:E9
    thawtepremiumserverca.1.1, Apr 23, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
.
.
.
```

But other OS has only 87 entries and same call is running fine.

Comment: Use KeyStore Explorer for having a look to certificates in the truststore . You can manage them with this tool(add, modify, delete...) On the other hand take a look to this post (comments). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218217/ssl-handshake-exception-algorithm-constraints-check-failed-md5withrsa ... I think you should use a previous java version  >"Starting from 7u40, the use of x.509 certificates with RSA keys less than 1024 bits in length is restricted." java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml . I tried change Java 7 to Java 6 and it worked. – venicum Jan 19 '14 at 15:08