# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException on Travis CI

Tags: java, android, travis-ci, robolectric

I have an android project that I'm attempting to test on Travis CI however when running the Robolectric (`v3.2.2`) tests I'm getting:

> com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on signature algorithm: SHA256WithRSAEncryption

This only happens on Travis and does not happen on my local machine (MacOS Sierra).

Any clues as to how to fix/workaround this error? Also, please let me know of any files/settings/etc that you'd like to see.

Comment: It looks like you have pinned SSL certificate and you're running real network connection in tests

Comment: @EugenMartynov Yes attempting to run real network connections. Any idea on how to get around this error?

Comment: Unfortunately, Volley was never part of my stack. I would advise to not use Robolectric for the integration tests. It will be another pain at another place. I would debug Volley http client part to get the point where from it takes TrustManager to validate certificate and then you might get a clue how to inject your certificate in Robolectric test

Comment: I'm unfortunately unable to remove Robolectric from our stack and it's also very hard to debug as this only happens within Travis CI's environment.

Comment: Can you try small tick? So in the setup of your test put next code: `ReflectionHelpers.setStaticField(Build.VERSION.class, "SDK_INT", 8)`. I have hope it will fix your problem.

Comment: @EugenMartynov Sadly I get the same result.

Comment: I believe it has to do with compatible jdk version.  See https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3288

Comment: See if this helps in anyway https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218217/ssl-handshake-exception-algorithm-constraints-check-failed-md5withrsa

Comment: What is jdk selected in your travis ci?

Comment: Can you share you travis yaml file?

Answer (score 2):

Import your certificates into the new cacerts file

```
$cp $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts

$keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias {cert alias} -file {cert file}
```

Restart the application.

Comment: Interesting! He is running on Travis CI but it might be key for the solution