# How to allow .NET to use insecure algorithms to validate certificates in SSL/TLS

Tags: c#, .net

We're trying to integrate with a service that uses a certificate signed with a now-considered insecure algorithm (we have no control over this). We managed to do it in Java by commenting the  line `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` in the `java.security` file (which is used exactly to disable validation through insecure algorithms), commented here [SSL handshake exception: "Algorithm constraints check failed: MD5withRSA"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218217/ssl-handshake-exception-algorithm-constraints-check-failed-md5withrsa)

However, I'm now trying to call the service from a .NET wcf auto-generated client but the code is throwing a `WebException`: `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel`. I believe it's for the same reason. How can I instruct the framework to accept any hashing algorithm when validating the certificate?

This is our code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ws = new ViabilidadePrefeituraWSClient();
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        { return true; };
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

    ws.recuperaViabilidadesPendentes("");
}
```

And this is our App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <diagnostics performanceCounters="Default" />
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="NewBehavior0">
                    <clientCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="false">
                        <clientCertificate findValue="www.santaluzia.mg.gov.br" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                        <serviceCertificate>
                            <defaultCertificate findValue="newsrmwildfly.jucemg.intranet"
                                storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                            <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" />
                        </serviceCertificate>
                    </clientCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="NewBinding2">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://wssecprefeituras.jucemg.mg.gov.br/empreendimento/service/ViabilidadePrefeituraWS"
                behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior0" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NewBinding2" contract="ViabilidadePrefeituraWS.ViabilidadePrefeituraWS"
                name="ViabilidadePrefeituraWSPort" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```